# Assigning items in lists to items in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm creating a game where I'd like to generate a name for 16 different planets from a bank of names and assign them to a planet. I've created an array for the planets and the name generation logic which are featured below.

```
    Planet[] planetArray = new Planet[16];

    public static void NameGeneration()
    {
         List<String> planetNames = new List<String>()
         {
             "Bak'hur",   "Etonia",      "Laurellan",
             "Ragki",     "Metiope",     "Defel", 
             "Liehne",    "Rykhan",      "Heito",
             "Makha",     "Cerbi",       "Helios",
             "Luruguan",  "Chawnos",     "T'hig",
             "Blana",     "Pergate V",   "Shemon III",
             "Yokteth",   "Letry",       "Last Besgino",
             "Ayus",      "Alterus",     "Qurenos"

         };

    List<Tuple<int>> instances = new List<Tuple<int>>();
    List<string> generatedNames = new List<string>();

    Random random = new Random();
    int planetName;


             //generating 16 names
         while(instances.Count < 16)
         {
             planetName = random.Next(0, planetNames.Count);

             Tuple<int> tuple = new Tuple<int>(planetName);

             if (instances.Contains(tuple))
             {
                 instances.Add(tuple);
             }
         }

         foreach (var tuple in instances)
         {
             generatedNames.Add(string.Format("{0}", planetNames[tuple.Item1]));
         }

         foreach (var n in generatedNames)
         { 

         }


    }
```

I really don't know where to go from here, though I have considered selecting from the list and assigning it manually, or randomising the planet aswell but I'd still be stuck in my tracks.

Any help or tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

Ryan

Comment: Why `Tuple<int>` instead of `int`?

Comment: try to declare the `new Random` from the outside in your method.

Comment: I used Tuple<int> because I'm new to programming and my tutor suggested I used it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this code does same thing - creates list of randomly picked 16 planet names:

```
var generatedNames = planetNames.OrderBy(n => random.Next()).Take(16).ToList();
```

Comment: Is that shorthand for the whole logic I used?

Comment: @Ryan'Maverick'Buxton exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to create the planets, after the random.  Something like:

```
planetArray = generatedNames.Select(x=>new Planet(x)).ToArray();
```

BTW, Why do you use List of Tuple of int?.  You can use List directly.

Comment: I used Tuple<int> because I'm new to programming and my tutor suggested I used it. How would I use it directly from List?

Comment: new Planet(x) - I get the error 'does not contain a contructor that takes 1 argument. What is the arguement?